# Overview of Scala method and function syntax

Tags: scala

I am learning Scala and I wonder if an overview of method/function syntax exists? When to use parantheses, different ways of writing etc. Also the conventions would be nice.

Comment: Do you mean [style guide](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think all the information you're requesting is in the [Scala docs](http://docs.scala-lang.org/).

Specifically, the [style guide](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/) and the [cheatsheet](http://docs.scala-lang.org/cheatsheets/).

Answer (score 2):

[Effective Scala](http://twitter.github.com/effectivescala/) from Twitter is also an excellent resource.  I've adopted it for all my Scala projects.